# Clarear figura VBA Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Boa tarde.
Estou precisando de uma macro para clarear uma figura, localizada na planilha, e reverter a coloração.

O Excel não grava a macro quando mudo as configurações na aba "Formatar". Já vasculhei o Google também de ponta a ponta.

Desde já agradeço muito.

Comment: Quando você clareia, qual o caminho no menu formatar? Qual ferramenta exatamente é utilizada?

Comment: @danieltakeshi estou usando o Microsoft Excel 2016. Eu uso a aba "Formatar", que aparece quando clico na figura, vou em "Cor" e escolho a opção "Escala de Cinza".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia @danieltakeshi.

Não era uma única imagem. O que eu fiz foi criar um retângulo branco com 30% de transparência, aí gravei a macro passando ele para trás da figura. ficou desse jeito:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 1")).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.ZOrder msoSendToBack 
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 4")).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.ZOrder msoSendToBack
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 14")).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.ZOrder msoSendToBack
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 3")).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.ZOrder msoSendToBack
```

Ia mudando conforme eu clicava na figura, fazendo um tipo de "Filtro".

Answer (score 0):

#### Única imagem da planilha

Caso seja a única imagem da planilha, utilize o seguinte código que transforma em escala de cinza a imagem de index 1.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1")
ws.Shapes(1).PictureFormat.ColorType = msoPictureGrayscale
```

#### Ou para selecionar a imagem desejada e depois executar o código

```
Sub escalaCinza()

 On Error GoTo err
    Dim oImg As Shape
    Dim ehImg As Boolean
    Set oImg = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    If oImg.Type = msoPicture Or oImg.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then ehImg = True
    If oImg.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
        If oImg.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoPicture Or oImg.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoLinkedPicture Then
            ehImg = True
        End If
    End If
    If Not ehImg Then
        err.Raise Number:=vbObjectError + 1000, Description:="Seleção não é imagem"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    oImg.PictureFormat.ColorType = msoPictureGrayscale
        Exit Sub
err:
    MsgBox err.Description
End Sub
```

#### Todas as imagens de uma planilha específica

```
Sub escalaCinza()

    On Error GoTo err
    Dim oImg As Shape
    Dim ehImg As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1")
    For Each oImg In ws.Shapes
        If oImg.Type = msoPicture Or oImg.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then ehImg = True
        If oImg.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
            If oImg.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoPicture Or oImg.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoLinkedPicture Then
                ehImg = True
            End If
        End If
        If Not ehImg Then
            err.Raise Number:=vbObjectError + 1000, Description:="Seleção não é imagem"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        oImg.PictureFormat.ColorType = msoPictureGrayscale
    Next oImg
    Exit Sub
err:
    MsgBox err.Description
End Sub
```

#### Todas as imagens da Pasta de Trabalho

```
Sub escalaCinza()

    On Error GoTo err
    Dim oImg As Shape
    Dim ehImg As Boolean
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        For Each oImg In ws.Shapes
            If oImg.Type = msoPicture Or oImg.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then ehImg = True
            If oImg.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
                If oImg.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoPicture Or oImg.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoLinkedPicture Then
                    ehImg = True
                End If
            End If
            If Not ehImg Then
                err.Raise Number:=vbObjectError + 1000, Description:="Seleção não é imagem"
                Exit Sub
            End If
            oImg.PictureFormat.ColorType = msoPictureGrayscale
        Next oImg
    Next ws
    Exit Sub
err:
    MsgBox err.Description
End Sub
```